# Splitting sentences from a .txt file to .csv using NLTK

Tags: csv, nlp, nltk, txt, sentence

I have a corpus of newspaper articles in a `.txt` file, and I'm trying to split the sentences from it to a `.csv` in order to annotate each sentence.

I was told to use `NLTK` for this purpose, and I found the following code for sentence splitting:

```py
import nltk

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

sent_tokenize("Here is my first sentence. And that's a second one.")
```

However, I'm wondering:

1. How does one use a `.txt` file as an input for the tokenizer (so that I don't have to just copy and paste everything), and
2. How does one output a `.csv` file instead of just printing the sentences in my terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reading a `.txt` file & tokenizing its sentences

Assuming the `.txt` file is located in the same folder as your Python script, you can read a `.txt` file and tokenize the sentences using `NLTK` as shown below:

```py
from nltk import sent_tokenize

with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    textFile = file.read()

tokenTextList = sent_tokenize(textFile)
print(tokenTextList)
# Output: ['Here is my first sentence.', "And that's a second one."]
```

---

### Writing a list of sentence tokens to `.csv` file

There are a number of options for writing a `.csv` file. Pick whichever is more convenient (e.g. if you already have `pandas` loaded, use the `pandas` option).

To write a `.csv` file using the `pandas` module:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(tokenTextList)
df.to_csv("myCSVfile.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

To write a `.csv` file using the `numpy` module:

```py
import numpy as np

np.savetxt("myCSVfile.csv", tokenTextList, delimiter=",", fmt="%s")
```

To write a `.csv` file using the `csv` module:

```py
import csv

with open('myCSVfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    write = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    # write.writerows([tokenTextList])
    write.writerows([[token] for token in tokenTextList]) # For pandas style output
```